# How to decrease the response time when dealing with SQL Server remotely?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have created a vb.net application that uses a SQL Server database at a remote location over the internet.

There are 10 vb.net clients that are working on the same time.

The problem is in the delay time that happens when inserting a new row or retrieving rows from the database, the form appears to be freezing for a while when it deals with the database, I don't want to use a background worker to overcome the freeze problem.

I want to eliminate that delay time and decrease it as much as possible

Any tips, advises or information are welcomed, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 2 problems:

> The form appears to be freezing for a while when it deals with the database, I don't want to use a background worker 
>   to overcome the freeze problem.

Vanity, arroaance and reality rarely mix. ANY operation that takes more than a SHORT time (0.1-0.5 seconds) SHOULD run async, only way to kep the UI responsive. Regardless what the issue is, if that CAN take longer of is on an internet app, decouple them.

But:

> The problem is in the delay time that happens when inserting a new records or retrieving records from the database,

So, what IS The problem? Seriously. Is this a latency problem (too many round trips, work on more efficient sql, batch, so not send 20 q1uestions waiting for a result after each) or is the server overlaoded - it is not clear from the question whether this really is a latency issue.

At the end:

> I want to eliminate that delay time

Pray to whatever god you believe in to change the rules of physics (mostly the speed of light) or to your local physician tof finally get quantum teleportation workable for a low cost. Packets take time at the moment to travel, no way to change that.

Check whether you use too many ound trips. NEVER (!) use sql server remotely with SQL - put in a web service and make it fitting the application, possibly even down to a 1:1 match to your screens, so you can ask for data and send updates in ONE round trip, not a dozen. WHen we did something similar 12 years ago with our custom ORM in .NET we used a data access layer for that that acepted multiple queries in one run and retuend multiple result sets for them - so a form with 10 drop downs could ask for all 10 data sets in ONE round trip. If a request takes 0.1 seconds internet time - then this saves 0.9 seconds. We had a form with about 100 (!) round trips (creating a tree) and got that down to less than 5 - talk of "takes time" to "whow, there". Plus it WAS async, sorry.

Then realize moving a lot of data is SLOW unless you have instant high bandwidth connections.

THis is exaclty what async is done for - if you have transfer time or latency time issues that can not be optimized, and do not want to use async, go on delivering a crappy experience.

Comment: TomTom is being a bit snarky here, but he makes excellent suggestions (given the limited info. Reducing round trips will e your biggest gain. Going to a web service would be a big gain. Reducing the amount of data will also help (don't do a select *, just get the columns you need, add compression to te web service calls if it's a lot of data).

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the SQL call asynchronously and let Microsoft deal with the background process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx

Please note, this does not decrease the response time from the SQL server, for that you'll have to try to improve your network speed or increase the performance of your SQL statements.

Comment: I don't want to execute the SQL call asynchronously because the form have to wait until the execution completes, I want to decrease the response time from the SQL server, Thank you anyway

Comment: Without seeing the SQL code, table indexes, etc. there's no way to help.

Comment: @Michaelharris If you have to wait for the response and you cannot make the server itself faster (eg. quicker storage) you are stuck: you cannot change the laws of physics.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could potentially do to speed things up, however it is difficult to  say without seeing the code.

1. If you are using generic inserts - start using stored procedures
2. If you are closing the connection after every command then... well dont. Establishing a    connection is typically one of the more 'expensive' operations
3. Increase the pipe between the two.
4. Add an index
5. Investigate your SQL Server perhaps it not setup in a preferred manner.